# How to link to an existing LDAP server in Windows for authentication

Tags: active-directory

So here's the deal. I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server that I want to have use an existing LDAP server for authentication and groups, etc.

In other words, I dont want to administer the accounts on the Windows 2008 server itself, but I want the server to think that they are there (like acting as a relay or repeater).

What I'm trying to do is have a way of having people access their Web published RemoteApp applications, but again, I dont want to manage the users on that server, there's already an existing LDAP server with all of that info.

Any ideas? Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.